# moment.js on dynamically created div creates issue. That last timeline replaces all other previous div

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I wanted to display timelines for various countries that are selected by user.

Below code works fine when it is executed for the first time:

```
var arrDivs = document.querySelectorAll('div[class^="myGeneratedDiv"]');
var timelineGraph = [];    
for (var i = 0; i < arrDivs.length; i++) {
  var oDiv = arrDivs[i];     
  var LocationName = oDiv.id.toString().split("_")[1];    
  var items = new vis.DataSet ([

    ]);     
    var timelineLocal = new vis.Timeline(document.getElementById(oDiv.id), items, {
      editable: true,
      start: start,
      end: end,
      moment: function (date) {
        return moment(date).tz(LocationName);

      },
      format: {
        minorLabels: {
          hour: 'hh:mm'
        }
      }
    });     
}
```

Each loop should display timeline for different country names. But it renders the timezone of last index country name to all the previously displayed timelines.

How can this be resolved?

Answer (score 0):

What is `new vis.Timeline` ? It seems that you are using the same div for instanciating your module. Try to create multiple target divs, like as follow:

```
var className = "country-timeline";
var countryList = ['en', 'fr'];
var containerList = countryList.map((country) => {
    return new vis.Timeline(document.getElementsByClassName(className)[i], items, {
        editable: true,
        start: start,
        end: end,
        moment: function (date) {
          return moment(date).tz(country)       
        },
        format: {
          minorLabels: {
            hour: 'hh:mm'
          }
        }
      });
});
```

In your html:

```
- <div id="odiv"></div>
+ <div class="country-timeline"></div>
+ <div class="country-timeline"></div>
```

Where `i` is the index of your loop, and `className` the target `div` for the country, you can have many.

Comment: Those are dynamically created div with different id's. I have updated the code including for loop. I also tried your above code as well which provides the same result.